# jMeter Login issue with MVC and Anti Forgery

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing, antiforgerytoken

I am trying to load test my Website using jMeter. 
I am getting issue with my login page. I have passed the __RequestVerificationToken value in login page by capturing it via RegEx as shown:

```
Field to check: Body.
Reference Name: token.
Regular Expression: <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.*)" />.
Template: $1$
```

I am still getting the same error with response as :

```
<title>The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the &lt;machineKey&gt; configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.</title>
<b> Exception Details: </b>System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the &lt;machineKey&gt; configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.<br><br>
```

More details from the Request tab in View tree results:

```
POST data:
__RequestVerificationToken=%24%7Btoken%7D&UserModel.UserName=pm&UserModel.Password=Abc1234D

Cookie Data:
ASP.NET_SessionId=l0cvy41ons0xv1t3e5glx2j5; __RequestVerificationToken_L0NyZWlzc1dlYg2=elGNi5_GoW2DYFM-obeXg9DHsihM26jv8HgT4IEpjngwc1gfJ4lRTboi3t-UV4L9485dM_9bdAVfRZKauTIXAZoKvNt2Q9R0yW19ZQIO17A1

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://172.52.50.137/CreissWeb/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Length: 91
Host: 172.52.50.137
```

HTTP Request:

```
__RequestVerificationToken  ${token}    false   true
UserModel.UserName  pm  false   true
UserModel.Password  Abc1234D    false   true
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. !!

Comment: Are you sure that  __RequestVerificationToken value is captured by RegEx as you expected? You need to provide more details.

Comment: Thanks, @VinothS. I have updated the question with more details, please take a look. Hope that helps !

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression extractor does not work as you expected. The POST data clearly shows that `__RequestVerificationToken=${token}`.

Try to change the Regular Expression to `name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.*)"` & see if it helps.

If it does not work, Post the HTTP response you get.